# Add a druid cluster as a SQL database in Apache Superset

Tags: sql, druid, apache-superset

I currently connect to the druid cluster through the druid connector in Apache Superset. I heard that SQL can be used to query druid. Is it possible to point my SQL database connection to druid?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow the steps below

1. You need to use latest version of `pydruid` for enabling sqlalchemy
   support. For me pydruid 0.4.1 is working fine.
2. On Superset, in the Databases section you need to provide the         `SQLAlchemy URI druid://XX.XX:8082/druid/v2/sql/`using a broker ip/host.
3. Third thing you need to do is to enable `druid.sql.enable=true` on
       broker.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sweet, I will try this out. Getting the enable piece may take a bit. I will accept your answer once I am able to fully test it.

Comment: It is in the `Databases` section under `Sources`, and not `Datasources` (which is also present, but it's not what you'd want).

Comment: @JohnStrood Thanks John. I have made the changes.

Comment: I tried HDP 2.6.5 with pydruid 0.4.5 installed then restarted superset, but still has "Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:druid" error，why?

Comment: I recently faced the same problem and this answer helped me. One thing to add, I don't know if this is new since this question was asked a year ago. You'd need to enable `Expose in SQL Lab` now in when you add source->databases

Comment: And if you have basic auth setup you can also use the form: druid://admin:pass@druid-host:8082/druid/v2/sql/

Answer (score 5):

i was really struggling with this one...  in my case, i am running on my mac.  druid is installed directly and superset is running in docker (using the docker-compose setup).

the key is that localhost in the superset docker container doesn't point at the host, but instead at the docker container.

when i changed the superset datasource to this, it worked...

```
druid://host.docker.internal:8082/druid/v2/sql/
```